# One staff with two sections and two voices

Tags: lilypond

In my piece, I want a single score in order to be able to output a single midi file.

The entire piece is polyphonic with two voices.

The structure should look like this:

```
chorus in two voices (with lyrics)
verses in two voices (with numbered lyrics)
```

I put together the structure below, but I don't want a piano staff or choir staff.  I just want one staff, but to have the chorus separated from the verses.  The chorus has one set of lyrics, the verses have another.

Now, I don't want to add the chorus lyrics to one of the verse lyrics and then use spacers as placeholders - because I am using a macro to number the verses lyrics.

```
\version "2.19.80"
\language "english"

%create new lyrics and add numbered lines
%creates:    \new Lyrics \with { instrumentName = "8." shortInstrumentName = "8." }
lyricsWithVerseNumber =
#(define-music-function (parser location number music)(number? ly:music?) #{
    \new Lyrics \with { instrumentName = #(string-append (number->string number) ".") shortInstrumentName = #(string-append (number->string number) ".")  }
    $music
#})    

  signature = {
      \key c \minor
  }
  chorusUpper = \relative c'' {
\signature
  g g g g
  }
  chorusLower = \relative c' {
\signature
  e e e e
  }
  versesUpper = \relative c'' {
\signature
  a a a a
  }
  versesLower = \relative c' {
\signature
  f f f f
  }

  chorusLyrics = \new Lyrics \lyricsto "chorus" {
    A song has words
  }
  wordsOne = \new Lyrics \lyricsWithVerseNumber 1 \lyricsto "verses" {
    More words for this
  }
  wordsTwo = \new Lyrics \lyricsWithVerseNumber 2 \lyricsto "verses" {
    Some words go here
  }
  wordsThree = \new Lyrics \lyricsWithVerseNumber 3 \lyricsto "verses" {
    Sing a bit more
  }

  \score {
      <<
          \time 4/4  
          \new Voice = "chorus" {\voiceOne \chorusUpper  }
          \new Voice { \voiceTwo \chorusLower }
          \chorusLyrics

          \new Staff {
              \new Voice = "verses" {\voiceOne \versesUpper  }
              \new Voice { \voiceTwo \versesLower }
          }
          \wordsOne
          \wordsTwo
          \wordsThree          

      >>
    \layout {
    }    

      %\midi { }
  }
```

How can I get the chorus with it's verse to show above the verses with their lyrics in a single score? With this code here it tries to create a choir staff - three staves joined together.

Comment: Maybe you could, please, stop posting non-working examples which use undefined escaped strings such as \signature. Either take them off, or define all macros in the same file.

Comment: I was figuring that folks more experienced than I would be able to look at my file construction and know how to arrange things without having to compile it.  As for the `\signature` I added it.

Comment: @bgmCoder I think that [the Minimum Working Example rule of TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) works the same for LilyPond questions. The whole thing is that **you** want some help, so **you** should make it as easy a possible for others to help you. That's why your code should be minimal to show the problem, but complete.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble.  Okay, I'll post working examples from now on.

Comment: I've updated the code for cut and paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this structure will work for your needs:

```
\version "2.19.81"
\language "english"

highVoiceChorus = \relative c' {
  e4. e4. | 
  e4 f8 g4. |
}

lowVoiceChorus = \relative c' {
  c4. c4. |
  c4 d8 e4. |
}

lyricsChorus = \lyricmode {
  Row, row, row your boat
}

highVoiceVerses = \relative c'' {
  c4 c8 c4 c8 |
  c4. c4. |
}

lowVoiceVerses = \relative c'' {
  g4 g8 a4 a8 |
  g4. g4. |
}

lyricsVerseOne = \lyricmode {
  \set stanza = "1. "
  Hap -- py hap -- py joy joy!
}

lyricsVerseTwo = \lyricmode { 
  \set stanza = "2. "
  Oh how hap -- py we are!
}

chorus = <<
  \new Voice = "highChorus" {
    \voiceOne
    \highVoiceChorus
  }
  \new Voice = "lowChorus" {
    \voiceTwo
    \lowVoiceChorus
  }
  \new Lyrics {
    \lyricsto "lowChorus" {
      \lyricsChorus
    }
  }
>>

verses = <<
  \new Voice = "highVerse" {
    \voiceOne
    \highVoiceVerses
  }
  \new Voice = "lowVerse" {
    \voiceTwo
    \lowVoiceVerses
  }
  \new Lyrics {
    \lyricsto "lowVerse" {
      \lyricsVerseOne
    }
  }
  \new Lyrics {
    \lyricsto "lowVerse" {
      \lyricsVerseTwo
    }
  }
>>

song = {
  \time 6/8
  \chorus
  \break
  \verses
}

\paper {
  ragged-right = ##t
}

\score {
  \new Staff \song
  \layout {
    indent = 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that is a lot different that the path I was taking.  But it does, indeed work!  I was thinking to keep the `<< >>` parts for the chorus and the verses directly in the `\score` context.

Comment: To clarify a bit, << >> is used to put simultaneous music. Instead, verses go sequentially after chorus. Here, @ksnortum used \break to make verses to appear visually below.

Comment: @bgmCoder, I am a strong believer in keeping the `\score` block small.  The more the code is broken into logical blocks, the better.  It helps to organize your code and makes maintenance easier.

Comment: Well, I am a programmer, and like to organize into OOP blocks, myself, so I'm not really disappointed.  Thanks for your help.  I've gotten my hymn fixed and used the same procedure to fix a similar one.